# Delete row from sqlite sync with Remote DB

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm having troubles deleting rows in the sqlite database.

What I'm trying to do is getting the Id's I want to delete from the Remote Database, and then use them to delete the rows in the SQLite DataBase.

But so far is not working

Here is where I first delete the items, and then insert items if needed.

```
// Method to Sync MySQL to SQLite DB
    public void syncSQLiteMySQLDB() {
        // Create AsycHttpClient object
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        // Http Request Params Object
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        // Show ProgressBar
        prgDialog.show();
        //Llamada HTTP a getdeletes.php
        client.post("http://restaurantechinaimperial.com/mysqlsqlitesync/getDeletes.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                deleteSQLite(response);
            }
        });
        // Make Http call to getplatos.php
        client.post("http://restaurantechinaimperial.com/mysqlsqlitesync/getplatos.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String response) {
                    // Hide ProgressBar
                    prgDialog.hide();
                    // Update SQLite DB with response sent by getusers.php
                    updateSQLite(response);
                }
                // When error occured
                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error, String content) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // Hide ProgressBar
                    prgDialog.hide();
                    if (statusCode == 404) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recurso no encontrado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (statusCode == 500) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Algo ha fallado en el servidor", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Inesperado! [Razon mas probable: El dispositivo no esta conectado a Internet]",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        });
    }
```

Here is the method which call the method in the sqlitecontroller to delete.

```
 public void deleteSQLite(String response){

        try {
            // Extract JSON array from the response
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
            System.out.println(arr.length());
            // If no of array elements is not zero
            if(arr.length() != 0){
                // Loop through each array element, get JSON object which has deleteid
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                    // Get JSON object
                    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);
                    String id=obj.getString("Id");
                    controller.deletePlato(id);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Here is the delete method on the sqlitehelper

```
 public void deletePlato(String deleteid){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        database.delete("platos", "platoId = 'deleteid'", null);
        database.close();   
    }
```

Can anybody help?